Title of a war movie set in the jungle at night with lots of rain and a training mission?
I am looking for the name of a movie i saw some years ago on TV. 
It is about a group US-soldiers who get send into the jungle for a training mission or survival training. The sergeant of the group is quite an asshole and has a personal problem with one of the soldiers in the group. It is raining heavily and one soldier has an "accident". After this the tension in the group rises and they split up. No one knows who killed the soldier and they dont trust each other. In the end i think the sergeant gets killed with a grenade, but i am not sure about this. It is dark and raining through the whole movie
I know it is very litte information but i would be very happy if someone knows this movie :) 

Didn't Platoon end with a fragging?

I'm not really sure, but this might be 2003's Basic, starring John Travolta and Samuel L. Jackson:

Tom Hardy, an ex-Army Ranger turned DEA agent, is drawn into an ever-widening mystery surrounding the disappearance of the feared and often hated Sgt. Nathan West, as well as several of his elite Special Forces trainees on what appears, at first, to have been a routine training exercise during a hurricane in the jungles of Panama. Only two survivors are found, Dunbar, and a badly wounded Kendall, the son of a high-profile Joint Chiefs of Staff official. Neither is willing to cooperate with Capt. Julia Osborne's investigation. So base commander Col. Bill Styles calls in ex-Ranger Hardy, an old friend and a persuasive interrogator. Osborne disapproves of Hardy who is on leave from the D.E.A. after having come under suspicion of accepting bribes from local drug traffickers. She is also uneasy when she learns that Hardy once trained under West and hates him almost as passionately as his current recruits. With time running out, Hardy and Osborne call a temporary, if uneasy, truce. Hardy ... 

The actual story of what happened during the training excercise pans out in various interviews all telling different versions of the story as flashbacks. This Rashomon-style storytelling also makes it hard for me to recount what actually happened, but I think some parts or versions of the story ivolved the death of a trainee and the suspicion between the soldiers, especially since the sergeant is indeed "quite and asshole" and is suspected by some soldiers to have deliberately caused the death of the other one. There were also grenades involved to some degree, I think.
